# XQuery "flattening" an element

Tags: xquery

I am extracting data from an XML file and I need to extract a delimited list of sub-elements. I have the following:

```
for $record in //record
let $person := $record/person/names
return concat($record/@uid/string()
  ,",", $record/@category/string()
  ,",", $person/first_name
  ,",", $person/last_name
  ,",", $record/details/citizenships
  ,"&#10;")
```

The element "citizenships" contains sub-elements called "citizenship" and as the query stands it sticks them all together in one string, e.g. "UKFrance". I need to keep them in one string but separate them, e.g. "UK|France".

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You could simplify this by asking only how to combine members of a sequence with a separator -- the rest of the context is arguably irrelevant.

Comment: @Charles Duffy - Yes, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fn:string-join($arg1 as xs:string*, $arg2 as xs:string)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-string-join) is what you're looking for here.

In your currently desired usage, that would look something like the following:

```
fn:string-join($record/details/citizenships/citizenship, "|")
```

---

Testing outside your document, with:

```
fn:string-join(("UK", "France"), "|")
```

...returns:

```
UK|France
```

Notably, `("UK", "France")` is a sequence of strings, just as a query returning multiple `citizenship`s would likewise be a sequence (the entries in which will be evaluated for their [string value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-typed-value) when passed to `fn:string-join()`, which is typed as taking a sequence of strings for its first argument).

---

Consider the following (simplified) query:

```
declare context item := document { <root>
  <record uid="1">
    <person>
      <citizenships>
        <citizenship>France</citizenship>
        <citizenship>UK</citizenship>
      </citizenships>
    </person>
  </record>
</root> };

for $record in //record
return concat(fn:string-join($record//citizenship, "|"), "&#10;")
```

...and its output:

```
France|UK
```

Comment: Technically, text() does not select strings, but text nodes.  Without entering into details, it is usually bad practice to use it.  Here, using simply `$record//citizenship` would make it more robust.

Comment: And of course, `//record` should be `$item//record`.

Comment: @FlorentGeorges, with 'declare context item` in use, `//record` is correct. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#dt-context-item, and http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-context-item-declarations

Comment: Oops, you're right, I read too quick, I saw a variable declaration instead.

Comment: ...as for directly selecting text nodes being bad practice, if a citizenship could contain markup I'd see your point.

Comment: @FlorentGeorges, ...beyond that, I've revised my answer to make fewer simplifications around typing &c.

Comment: Even only this would affect using `text()` (I agree it is very unlikely in this example, just saying it is best practice): `<citizenship>U<!-- -->K</citizenship>`.